Getting the following error when trying to install Apache Airflow
I am using Windows 11.
I have downloaded the pip for Apache Airflow, but when I try to run 'airflow db init', I get the following error:
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\airflow\__init__.py:35: RuntimeWarning: Airflow currently can be run on POSIX-compliant Operating Systems. For development, it is regularly tested on fairly modern Linux Distros and recent versions of macOS. On Windows you can run it via WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2) or via Linux Containers. The work to add Windows support is tracked via https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388, but it is not a high priority.
  warnings.warn(
OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\airflow.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\airflow\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\airflow\settings.py", line 536, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\airflow\settings.py", line 238, in configure_orm
    raise AirflowConfigException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: `sqlite:///C:\Users\dell\airflow/airflow.db` to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as `sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db`.

I tried running init command, and then finding the cfg file to change SQLite to PostgreSQL, but my cfg file is not being created.

After reading the error message, and what it says about running on Windows, what did you try?

did you tried installed airflow with docker? Use the doker-compose.yaml file https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml

Thank you so much for your help, I installed it using WSL.
